# subjective question: when to use multi master db setup vs sharding

Tags: database, tradeoff

I've been doing some reading about multi master setups. I could just not wrap my head around conflicts. why not use a sharded DB setup?

Here are some cons of a sharded db,

- need an additional component, a shard manager
- requires resharding when the db topology changes

am i missing something?

whereas, a multi master db requires conflict detection and resolution, assuming, high write throughput system results in frequent conflicts.

When would one typically pick one solution over the other?

if my assumption is correct, multi master db is useful when conflict resolution is straightforward for the given data schema and outweighs the shard management overhead?

Please share some examples.